# How to edit the label color for published or not published in Admin?

Tags: views

I tried to change the color of the text under the "Published" column of the node content listing.

I need the published text to be in green color and the unpublished text to be in red color.

In the view I have edited the output of the following field:

**Administration: Nodes (Content)**

**Configure field: Content: Published**

Rewrite Output :

`<span class="label label-success">[status]</span>`

Please check the screen shot for a better understanding.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to do that, one may be the implementation of the following preprocess function: [hook_preprocess_views_view_table](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view_table/7.x-3.x). Here is a code sample:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_views_view_table.
 */
function my_module_preprocess_views_view_table(&$vars) {
  $view = $vars['view'];
  $results = $vars['result'];
  if ($view->name == 'my_view_administration_nodes' ) {
    foreach ($results as $row => $result) {
      $vars['field_classes']['status'][$row] .= $result->node_status ? ' published' : ' not-published';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When i added this code i got the following results: <td class="views-field views-field-status"> Not published </td>

Comment: @Harikris Updated answer. Note that, that  view of yours is an [admin View](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views) for manipulating content, which means that the implementation of any preprocess function in the default theme will not be triggered, and if you insist to trigger one you'll have to [sub-theme](https://www.drupal.org/node/1010576) the seven theme. Given that, the `preprocess_views_view_table` should be implemented in a module file instead of the `template.php` file.